# issue with MAX statement in t-sql code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is the code:

```
Select BCPP.*
from ViewPBCPP   BCPP
inner join
( 
Select MBC.PC     PC
      ,MRT.Name   CT
      ,Max(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate)) as LRDate
from TableBACC    MBC

inner join TableSC.RT   MRT
ON MBC.RTid = MRT.id
where MBC.Isdeleted = 'False'
and MBC.PC <> 'NULL'
Group by MBC.PC
        ,MRT.Name
) MBCR
ON BCPP.P_id = MBCR.PC
and BCPP.CreatedDate = MBCR.LRDate
and BCPP.CT = MBCR.CT
```

Now  `Max(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate))` is actually a function

Query above works fine with `Max(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate))`

Now when I write

```
Max(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate)) + Min(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate))
```

I cannot extract any values at all from this query written above

If I write just

```
(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate))
```

it gives me error that it does not contained aggregate function or the group by function

I actually want this

```
(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate))
```

so that I can use all the values of this function rather than just MAX values of it

How can I change this code written above to achieve my objective??

Anyone??

Comment: Do you mean to use `dbo.CalcDatefromUTC( MAX(MBC.CreatedDate))` ?

Comment: I dont want to use MAX as MAX will give me only the latest values of the dates from the function. I want to change this so that I can use all the dates values calculated by this function and not just Latest or Max date values.If I remove Max the way code is written I get aggregate function or group by function error

Comment: Then why do you use `GROUP BY MBC.PC, MRT.Name` ?

Comment: You can `GROUP BY MBC.PC, MRT.Name, MBC.CreatedDate` instead.

Comment: because MBC.PC
        ,MRT.Name are from 2 different tables and are important

Comment: dbo.CalcDatefromUTC() function calculates datetime between start and end.

Comment: That is not very helpful. First, you use `CreatedDate` while the fields probably store datetimes. AFAIK, SQL-server-2008 has `DATE` type. Second, you say the function calculates a difference (between start and end) but it has only one parameter. What is the start and what is the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate)` in the `SELECT` list as neither you can have `MBC.CreatedDate` because it's not in the `GROUP BY` list.

You can have `MAX(MBC.CreatedDate)` though because it uses an aggregate function (MAX) on thta column. You can also have:

```
dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MAX(MBC.CreatedDate)) as LRDate
```

which is the same actually (although maybe a bit faster), as:

```
MAX(dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate)) as LRDate
```

---

From your comments, I assume the above is not very helpful. Perhaps grouping by `MBC.CreatedDate` as well is what you want:

```
Select BCPP.*
from ViewPBCPP   BCPP
inner join
( 
Select MBC.PC     PC
      ,MRT.Name   CT
      ,dbo.CalcDatefromUTC(MBC.CreatedDate) as LRDate
from TableBACC    MBC

inner join TableSC.RT   MRT
ON MBC.RTid = MRT.id
where MBC.Isdeleted = 'False'
and MBC.PC <> 'NULL'
Group by MBC.PC
        ,MBC.CreatedDate                  --- added
        ,MRT.Name
) MBCR
ON BCPP.P_id = MBCR.PC
and BCPP.CreatedDate = MBCR.LRDate
and BCPP.CT = MBCR.CT
```

Comment: It means you have more rows in the subquery resultset, one row for every different `(MBC.PC, MBC.CreatedDate, MRT.Name)` combination. So, yes, no `MBC.CreatedDate` will get "lost" during the grouping. Not at all sure if that's what you want though. Try it out.

Comment: If you tell us what this `dbo.CalcDatefromUTC()` function does, we may get an idea of what the query does.

Comment: dbo.CalcDatefromUTC() function calculates VDate as datetime between startVDate and endVDate. It returns DateTime

Comment: dbo.CalcDatefromUTC() function calculates VDate as datetime between start and end period. It returns DateTime